# Is it a bug in the design of a low side UCC27524A, and 2EDN7424 gate driver if it doesn't use VDD capacitor?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, layout, semiconductors, packages

I am using low-side TI and Infineon gate drivers.

If I don't use a VDD capacitor, then there is a glitch in the output waveform as shown in the figures. It seems it's the designer's or layout problem but I'm not sure about it.

Can anybody give me a suggestion on what kind of problem it could be a and how to correct it?

[image]

Comment: Please add a schematic showing the circuit being tested. There is a schematic editor available when you edit your question.

Comment: I am just giving 5V to input and enable pins. The test environment is like to determine the UVLO. So the given glitch in the given waveform can only be seen when I reached VDD near the UVLO point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you know the answer already. If the scope picture is the vdd drooping when the output turns on, then that is evidence that your vdd supply does need bypassing. It is the exact reason for the bypass caps. You might also want to look for potential ground bounce as well. As for any magic solution, sorry. You’ll just have to add the capacitor and spin a new board.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you share some documents or links about potential ground bounce?

Comment: It really boils down to understanding the inductance of the pcb or other interconnects. Knowing the currents and di/dt involved and an estimation of the inductances in the current paths can you determine whether you have a problem or not. I’d be Googling ‘ground bounce on mosfet source’ or suchlike. The likes of Infineon/IR should have app notes.

Comment: Because of the very fast edges on your signals, it is also important that you are really measuring the signals correctly with a suitable wide bandwidth CRO probe using a ground spring rather than the customary long ground lead. Many ringing and unusual waveform problems associated with MOSFET Drivers turn out to be measurement artifacts, so it might be worth checking your measurement setup before making expensive changes.